# About Error in MySQL login

Tags: mysql

I have installed just now MySQL on the Computer.

Now when I open the command prompt it says:

> Could not open required defaults file: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini
>
> Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
>
> Enter password:

But I don't know the password even on the time of installation it doesn't ask anything about password. I don't know anything about MySQL.

Help is needed.
Thanks.

Comment: Does `my.ini` exist in the path you see in the error? Is it readable by whatever user you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68482

Is there a chance your using XP?

Also related to the password have a look at how to reset it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, and it was really driving me crazy. The error in my case was that there was a mysqld executable from older installation aside from the binaries Iam using.

`which mysqld`
pointed to `/usr/sbin/mysqld`
while it should point to `/opt/mysql-server`
I guess that was a leftover from previous installation.
My binaries are installed somewhere else , so removing the old installation binaries
`rm /usr/sbin/mysqld`
did the trick.
Now, 
`which mysqld`
points correctly to 
`/opt/mysql-server/bin/mysqld`